# Wordpress require a php file in a required php file in custom template flile

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have a three php file, template-file.php, get-user.php, and number.php. Currently I have required get-user.php in template-file.php. But i have a problem in get-user.php to required number.php. How do i required, number.php in get-user.php. Below is my code.

```
//template-file.php
<?php
    require get_theme_file_path('inc/get-user.php'); //this is working
?> 
//get-user.php
<?php
    require get_theme_file_path('utils/number.php'); //not working.
    class User{
        $_Number;
        public function __construct(){
            $this->_Number = new Number();
        }
    
?>
```

Comment: check file path to exists and check file name uppercase and lower case

Comment: I did already , it says "Cannot declare class Number, because the name is already in use in"

Answer (score 0):

you must check this class not declared before
you must add this condition to  number.php and this class

```
if(!class_exists("Number"))
{
   class Number
   {
      //do anything
   }
}
```

Comment: Im certain already that i dont have other class with the name number

Comment: possible other plugin use that class name or required twice , for example : if your code in loop you gave this error . please check your twice call in other section of your project or loops